# Nested Looping use Regex python

Tags: python, regex, loops

I want to ask.

- url = [domaina.com/def, domainb.com/abc, domainc.com/]
- payload = [abc, def, ghi]

how to call url and payload together using regex if match, for example:

- domaina.com/abc
- domaina.com/def

then

- domainb.com/abc
- domainb.com/def

  ```py
  import re
  import csv
  import collections

  def log_file_reader(filename):

   f = open(filename, "r")
      #log = f.read()
      #payload = a.read() 
   for url in f:
    a = open("xss.txt", encoding='utf-8')
    for payload in a:
     #regex = r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
     ip_list = re.findall(payload, url)
     return ip_list
     #print(payload, url)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_file_reader('url')
  ```

Comment: What do you mean by `call url and payload together using regex`? Judging from your code, the expected result will be the list of url which matches the payload: `domaina.com/def` and `domainb.com/abc`, correct?

Comment: Yes, the expected results show a list of urls that match the existing payload

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. I have posted an answer. I hope it will meet your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try something like:

```
def log_file_reader(filename):
    # assuming files are already opened as f and a
    l = []
    for url in f:
        for payload in a:
            if re.search('/' + payload + '$', url):
                l.append(url)
    return l
```

With the provided examples, it will return:

```
['domaina.com/def', 'domainb.com/abc']
```

I have prepended `/` and appended `$` to the string `payload` to avoid the possible partial match (e.g. `ab` or `ef` are given in the payload list).